# Determining the Orientation of the screen rather than the orientation of the device

Tags: ios, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

The `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` method returns a number of orientations beyond the portrait and landscape orientation.  I am well aware of checking to see if the orientation returned is "valid", unfortunately if the orientation returned is NOT "valid" when my app requires a specific orientation to determine which methods to run, I have no way of knowing which method is appropriate.

I have attempted a number of solutions to this, but for now the only thing I have been able to work out is to check to see if the orientation is `LandscapeLeft` or `LandscapeRight` and if it isn't I assume the screen is in portrait orientation.  Unfortunately this isn't true when the device is face up and the screen is in landscape orientation.

I attempted to use the parent view controller's orientation:

```
parentController.interfaceOrientation;
```

Unfortunately it returned `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`.  I search SO and Google for someone else who has faced this problem.  It seems silly to me that Apple would have anything but `LandscapeLeft/Right` and `PortraitUp/Down` for their orientations.

What I really need is the APPS orientation not the devices, since these are sometimes at odds.  Any advice?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Have you tried using `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`/`UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape`?  I usually have pretty good results using these methods:

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(viewController.interfaceOrientation)) {
    //do portrait work
} else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(viewController.interfaceOrientation)){
    //do landscape work
}
```

You might also try [UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation).

These will only return the app's orientation, which may not be the same as the device's orientation.

If those don't work, you can also try:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```