# Get default device orientation (Landscape or Portrait) on Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, orientation, screen-orientation

I am currently working with Unity3D and I need to find out how to determine default device orientation (landscape or portrait) for both Android and iOS. What is the best way to achieve this through code (I'm working with c#) ?

Thanks for the help !

Note : I've seen the following post : [How to check device natural (default) orientation on Android (i.e. get landscape for e.g., Motorola Charm or Flipout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape)

But I can't seem to make the code work (maybe I'm missing a file to import or something). Besides, I need a way to make this work with iOS as well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found what I needed by myself !

Here's the link, for anyone interested : https://gist.github.com/flarb/3252857

(I didn't need the iOS check in the end, since our application is only supported on tablets anyway, plus I think the default orientation on all iOS devices is Portrait (might be wrong))

Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

For Android you could use  [getRotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29) :

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

switch (rotation) {
case 0:
    return Surface.ROTATION_0;
case 90:
    return Surface.ROTATION_90;
case 180:
    return Surface.ROTATION_180;
case 270:
    return Surface.ROTATION_270;`
```

For iOS [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559652/how-do-i-detect-the-orientation-of-the-device-on-ios) might help :

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = 
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if(orientation == 0) //Default orientation
//UI is in Default (Portrait) -- this is really a just a failsafe. 
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
//Do something if the orientation is in Portrait
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
// Do something if Left
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
//Do something if right
```

Also, this thread has similar answer : [Determining the Orientation of the screen rather than the orientation of the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022141/determining-the-orientation-of-the-screen-rather-than-the-orientation-of-the-dev)

Comment: I should add, if you have explicitly set the orientation of the activity to be landscape / portrait, the value from 'getRotation()' will not take this into account and return the wrong 'natural' orientation (which would be whatever you've requested the orientation to be).

Comment: your `rotation` is constant 0, 1, 2, or 3, which are Surface.ROTATION_0, 90, 180, 270. Therefore your switch statement needs to be edited. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#ROTATION_0